# How to access Android APKs without rooting

Tags: backup, apk

I recently bought a 7" Android ICS tablet as a gift for a friend.  Unfortunately it's not a Store supported device, so I can't download from the Store.

There are a number of sites that allow you to download APKs, but most of the apps I want to download aren't available on them.  I have a 10" tablet that IS supported and has a large number of the apps I want to provide to my friend.  Is there any way to get at the APKs on the 10" tablet (without rooting it) so I can copy them to, and install them on the 7" - using the provided app installer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an app like [App Backup & Restore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.infolife.appbackup). It allows you to select which apps you want to backup and it copies them to your SD card.

Comment: Titanium Backup is useful for this too.  The APKs are stored in a folder on the root of the SD card called "backup", if memory serves :)

Comment: @Logos it's "TitaniumBackup". But that requires root and the question was for without that. That's way the first paid app I bought and it saved my ass a few times :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that app backups don't require root?  Also, there *is* a space between the two words, but thanks for playing :) http://matrixrewriter.com/android/

Comment: OK, so I got App Backup and Restore to backup the apps ad restored them onto the 7"...  BUT... (There's always a "but" isn't there?  But, NOT all the apps in my app list appear on the list that I can backup.  What's going on here?

Comment: @Logos I meant the folder's name not th app'. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try with a [file browser (Astro)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.metago.astro&hl=en) or something like that to browse on your tablet and then you'll find the apk's if you search good.
But it is not sure they will work correctly or possible to transport them. But you can always give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

I can't put a comment so l'm answering which will be extension to Fox Hayden's answer.  On tablet which has many apps as you said install SHAREit. In SHAREit there is option named web share . It can used to transfer all files including SHAREit.apk. Just follow the instructions given in web share. Now install SHAREit on client too. Transfer whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Best choice for this is IMHO [AppMonster](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.android_telefonie.appmanager), which backs up your `*.apk` files to sdcard. This version is free but somehow limited; the real power comes with its payed version, [AppMonster Pro Backup Restore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.think_android.appmanagerpro) (~EUR 3) -- which not only adds batch-mode for restore, but also automatically backs up all new installations/updates, while letting you define how many generations you want to keep and (at least this was on the roadmap) even "pin" a version you want to keep "forever".

An added plus is that it also shows whether an app has ad modules hooked in (e.g. AdMob), if it supports App2SD, or if it is already installed on SD:

[image: AppMonster Pro] [image: AppMonster AppOptions] [image: AppMonster backed up AppVersions]

For me, it is the ultimate tool for this goal -- saved my ass a couple of times, when some app-update introduced a bug, or ripped away a feature. The only thing I miss here is it cannot backup the apps' data -- but that's a thing impossible to all non-root apps (for this, I use mentioned [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup) -- but that's not topic of this question, and thus just mentioned for completeness).

To sum up: *AppMonster* would solve your problem with getting the `*.apk` files to the sdcard for transfer -- and even offer you features you surely will use even after completing that job. Moreover, if you use the Pro version, the sdcard copy will be done automatically for you, saving you some manual work.

Comment: Titanium Backup (free) on un-rooted device can also do what App Monster pro can do. So, why should I spend money?

Comment: So you say, TB automatically backs-up .apk files at the moment you do the install/update? I must have missed something in its settings then. But thanks for the info that TB can also be used on un-rooted devices!

Comment: OP isn't asking for instant auto-backup. BTW, ROM Toolbox provides this feature for free..

Comment: Feel free to provide your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

1) Download zapya on any other device than share it to your device using bluetooth install it and you can connect both devices through Zapya using wifi hotspot and Zapya will let you send and receive APK of any app .

2) Download ES file explorer open it and click on apps it will show you all the apk's of installed apps.

Answer (score -1):

1. Download SHAREit on both devices.
2. Press 'receiver' on the gift tablet and 'sender' on the other.
3. Go to Apps on the sender then select the apps you want to share.

Comment: [SHAREit](http://shareit.lenovo.com/download.html) doesn't provide a direct download, so how do you propose getting it on the tablet that can't access the Play Store?