# Extract the apk of Live wallpapers

Tags: live-wallpaper

To extract the apk of any android application , it is simple just use any apk extractor tool and get the apk. However in the case for live wallpapers the apk extractor do not show the apk for wallpapers .

I just want to get the apk for live wallpapers from my phone .

Comment: See also: [How to access Android APKs without rooting](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/27780/16575), [How do I save purchased apps as APKs?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/49114/16575)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ES File Exporer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop&hl=en)

1. Goto App Manager (press menu to get app manager)
   `There you can see list of applications installed in your mobile`
2. Select Live wallpaper apk
3. click on Backup
4. You can find apk in location /sdcard/backups/apps

****Edit:****

System Live Wallpapers are located on your phone in path:

> **system/app/LiveWallpapers.apk**

You can use ES File Explorer for the same.
**But your device need to be rooted to access system apps.**

Comment: its no working .. ES File Explorer not showing any ofthe live wallpaper apk

Comment: Are you talking about system Live wallpapers?

Comment: Yes i think i am talking about system wallpapers.

Comment: edited answer above